# Knockout, selectable table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm using KO.js to bind a table body with many rows. If the user clicks anywhere on the row, I want that row be highlighted.

this is my code sofar

Html

```
 <table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Last Edited</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Preview</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectItem, css: {'selected':$root.selectedItem() == $data}">
            <td style="width: 27px"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Pre</td>
            <td>Del</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
var App = new function () {
   var self = this;

// Public Properties
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(App);
```

Css

```
.selected
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

this is the fiddle of what I have go so far

http://jsfiddle.net/Z53dB/

There are similar questions on SO and I have followed them so far but I
 am not having much success

Can anyone advise, on what I am missing

thanks

Comment: Why not just use jQuery to `toggleClass('selected')` on all `<td>` elements?

Answer (score 3):

You bind `click` to `selectItem` function without `selectItem` function.

```
self.selectItem = function( data ) {
    self.selectedItem( data );
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z53dB/1/

Comment: Here's an example when data-bound to multiple rows:  http://jsfiddle.net/Z53dB/2/