# How to change row order of table using knock out. Either drag and drop or using Up/Down buttons

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

How do I change the row order of table using knockout. I have the fiddle:

Using knockout-sortable.js. Example

Please assist.
My fiddle is below:

JSFiddle Example

```
  [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/hw9B2/
  [2]:https://jsfiddle.net/nagarajputhiyavan/x9vc10zu/3/
```

Comment: @DieterMeemken I want to change the row order of the table, I mean moving the rows position.

Comment: Thanks for the edit - @cpoDesign

Comment: How would you like this to change? Like, if this is sorted by some value before displaying it in the table, or would the reordering be done by user interaction like clicking on something (e.g. arrow)?

Comment: Like drag and drop or. by selecting the row and having a button up/down to move up/down.

Comment: An idea or link atleast would suffice.

Comment: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the whole idea of Knockout is that you work with your data model and Knockout keeps the UI in sync with it, the fundamental problem is simply reordering your array (and it needs to be an `observableArray` for Knockout to notice changes to it).

Of the two methods you suggested, the Up and Down buttons are easier, so that's what I went with. I added Up and Down buttons to each row, and disabled Up for the first row and Down for the last row.

The Up button is `click`-bound to a `moveUp` function that splices out the current row and splices it back in a row up. The Down does the same thing, but splicing back in a row down.

```js
var AppModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  this.itemsToReceive = ko.observableArray([{
    RecordId: 1,
    IsPriority: true,
    IsInTransit: true,
    IsSpecialRecall: true
  }, {
    RecordId: 2,
    IsPriority: false,
    IsInTransit: true,
    IsSpecialRecall: true
  }, {
    RecordId: 3,
    IsPriority: false,
    IsInTransit: true,
    IsSpecialRecall: true
  }]);
  
  this.moveUp = function(data) {
    var idx = self.itemsToReceive.indexOf(data),
      tmp = self.itemsToReceive.splice(idx, 1);

    self.itemsToReceive.splice(idx - 1, 0, tmp[0]);
  };
  
  this.moveDown = function(data) {
    var idx = self.itemsToReceive.indexOf(data),
      tmp = self.itemsToReceive.splice(idx, 1);

    self.itemsToReceive.splice(idx + 1, 0, tmp[0]);
  };
  
  this.loadGridServerSide = function() {
    self.itemsToReceive([{
      RecordId: 1,
      IsPriority: true,
      IsInTransit: true,
      IsSpecialRecall: true
    }]);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: loadGridServerSide" class="btn btn-primary">Server Side Invoke</button>
<table class="table static-table table-bordered table-hover no-bottom-margin">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item Number</th>
      <th>Priority?</th>
      <th>Transit?</th>
      <th>SpecialRecall?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: itemsToReceive">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: RecordId"></td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsPriority" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsInTransit" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSpecialRecall" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button data-bind="disable: $index() === 0, click: $parent.moveUp">Up</button>
        <button data-bind="disable: $index() === $parent.itemsToReceive().length - 1, click: $parent.moveDown">Down</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Using Drag and Drop would be somewhat more complicated, because the re-ordering happens in the UI and needs to be reflected into the data model. You would do it in a custom binding handler, and [such a handler has been written](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable). Here is [an article about it](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html).

Comment: Thats really great and Thanks. I am still looking for something like using single Up and Single Down button outside the table and doing the row movements by selecting the row. I will try from this. Is that easy from here?

Comment: It's certainly possible. There's just a little more bookkeeping about which row is selected.

Comment: any idea how to make the row selectable?

Comment: @RustinCohle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658284/knockout-selectable-table-row

Comment: I have done it and I am facing another chanllenge. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nagarajputhiyavan/cvcumgyk/ Is there a way to make a table cell editable to textbox on click? Thanks in advance.